# Apex Model : Illegal Value for Primitive

Tags: apex, json, class, object-model

I was trying to avoid posting this on here with so many threads on this topic, but I am really hoping someone can help me figure out what I'm missing here.

I keep receiving an "Illegal Value for Primitive" error on my Class but I can't figure out where. I did try to use the JSON2APEX heroku app but due to the Strings "1" and "2" located in the QuerySalesResult Object the class it creates doesn't actually work so I had to try to make it from scratch.

I have provided the Class I built, an example JSON Response, and the line I'm using to parse the response.

Any and all assistance will be greatly appreciated!

**APEX Class - Case Details**

```
public class CaseDetails {

    public class First {
        public String USR_USERNAME;
    }
    
    public class Second {
        public String USR_USERNAME;
    }

    public class QuerySalesResult {
        public First First;
        public Second Second;
    }

    public String SYS_LANG;
    public String SYS_SKIN;
    public String SYS_SYS;
    public String APPLICATION;
    public String PROCESS;
    public String TASK;
    public Integer INDEX;
    public String USER_LOGGED;
    public String USR_USERNAME;
    public String APP_NUMBER;
    public String PIN;
    public String ServiceRep;
    public String SubmitDate;
    public String CustomerName;
    public String Company;
    public String ContactName;
    public String CustomerContactNumber;
    public String CustomerEmailAddress;
    public String CustomerAddress;
    public String ApartmentSelection;
    public String City;
    public String State;
    public String Zipcode;
    public String SubdivisionSelection;
    public String RequestTypeMain;
    public String ServiceTypeRequested;
    public String NextRoutingGroup;
    public String Source;
    public String Rep;
    public String UserEmail;
    public String SalesSupportMemberBegan;
    public QuerySalesResult QuerySalesResult;
    public String UsersFoundMessage;
    public String VarChanged;
    
    public static CaseDetails parse(String json) {
        return (CaseDetails) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CaseDetails.class);
    }
}
```

**JSON - Example Response**

```
{
    "SYS_LANG": "en",
    "SYS_SKIN": "neoclassic",
    "SYS_SYS": "workflow",
    "APPLICATION": "64637120363067e726c30d2039563209",
    "PROCESS": "81243839356426812f20202086265219",
    "TASK": "735078682564268abd74659056301709",
    "INDEX": 1,
    "USER_LOGGED": "48346802763066bd151bba3065154523",
    "USR_USERNAME": "",
    "APP_NUMBER": "38149",
    "PIN": "6SH2",
    "ServiceRep": "Bob Stewart",
    "SubmitDate": "08-24-2022",
    "CustomerName": "Big Guy",
    "Company": "CompanyRKHL",
    "ContactName": "Bob Stewart",
    "CustomerContactNumber": "123-456-789",
    "CustomerEmailAddress": "bob.stewart@fakemail.com",
    "CustomerAddress": "101 Fake Address Lane",
    "ApartmentSelection": "AptSelectionApartment",
    "City": "Charleston",
    "State": "StateSC",
    "Zipcode": "29401",
    "SubdivisionSelection": "SubSelectionNA",
    "RequestTypeMain": "RequestTypeNewConstruction",
    "ServiceTypeRequested": "ServiceTypeRequestedTelephone",
    "NextRoutingGroup": "Assignment",
    "Source": "SalesForceBus",
    "Rep": "SalesForceUser",
    "UserEmail": null,
    "SalesSupportMemberBegan": "No",
    "QuerySalesResult": {
        "1": {
            "USR_USERNAME": "abcdefg"
        },
        "2": {
            "USR_USERNAME": "JessicaDrew"
        }
    },
    "UsersFoundMessage": "Users were found in group 'Sales Support'.",
    "__VAR_CHANGED__": "UserEmail,Rep,CaseNumber,SalesSupportMemberBegan,QuerySalesResult,SalesSupportMemberBegan,UsersFoundMessage,SubjectInsideIf,return,APPLICATION,return,APPLICATION,EmailSalesUsersFound"
}
```

**APEX Call**

```
CaseDetails cd1 = CaseDetails.parse(res.getBody());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not entirely sure how the specific error you're getting comes to be, but I think that you have narrowed it down to the problematic element(s).

Identifiers (class names, method names, variable names) in Apex cannot start with a number. So any JSON attribute that starts with a number is going to be problematic.

If you can modify the JSON at the source (or in Apex, before you deserialize) to change

```
"QuerySalesResult": {
        "1": {
            "USR_USERNAME": "abcdefg"
        },
        "2": {
            "USR_USERNAME": "JessicaDrew"
        }
    },
```

to use a list/array instead

```
"QuerySalesResult": [
        {
            "USR_USERNAME": "abcdefg"
        },
        {
            "USR_USERNAME": "JessicaDrew"
        }
    ],
```

Then you'd be able to get a new deserialization class from the JSON2Apex tool that should work (for typed deserialization). If you don't need the `QuerySalesResult` information, you may be able to get away with simply removing `public QuerySalesResult QuerySalesResult;` from the deserialization class (which may cause the deserialization to skip trying to process it).

Otherwise, this is going to be something that you need to use `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` on (with all of the extra typecasting it entails).

Comment: Confirmed that simply removing `public QuerySalesResult QuerySalesResult;` does work. Though in doing so I learned that the original code isn't giving me any error (when modified to be able to be executed via anonymous apex). "first" and "second" simply don't get populated.

Comment: Thanks for you assistance! Is there anything special you had to do when you removed the QuerySalesResult variable? I don't need this information but I was under impression that I needed to map all of the response variables in the deserialization class. 

I commented out ```public QuerySalesResult QuerySalesResult;``` and the corresponding inner classes, but I still receive the "illegal value for primitive" error when I try to run the ```CaseDetails.parse(res.getBody())``` command from an Anon Apex window.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the QuerySalesResult member a Map.

Change:

```
public QuerySalesResult QuerySalesResult;
```

To:

```
public Map<String, UserDetail> QuerySalesResult;
```

Where UserDetail is:

```
public class UserDetail {
  public String USR_USERNAME;
}
```

This would allow you to do something like:

```
CaseDetails detail = CaseDetails.parse(jsonString);
for(UserDetail theUser: detail.QuerySalesResult.values()) {
  System.debug(theUser.USR_USERNAME);
}
```

I do agree that it'd be better to change your JSON, as Derek suggested, but if you really don't want to change your JSON, this is a suitable alternative.

Comment: I ended up getting the developer to change the JSON, thanks so much for your help!